# obtainUsername not called a custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter Java config

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

edited : method obtainUsername is not called  . the code goes into

```
 doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain)
```

but not in

```
protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request)
```

I added a custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in websecurity config but it wont goes into the method method obtainUsername in  debug mode ( so I guess it is not reached )

```
WebSecurityConfig
        http
            .csrf().disable() //TODO Refactor login form
            .addFilter(**customAuthenticationFilter**)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout/success")
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login/failure")
                .permitAll();
```

In the logs I got  :

```
Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, 
[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1a70127, 
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@8ea2c0, 
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1cac116, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3620e6, 
**customAuthenticationFilter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f8a98275@13cad6b**, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@fe809c, 
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5f0635, 
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@9081c3, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@9d4c6f, 
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4acbdf, 
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1ad3fb8, 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2dfa56]
```

thanks

Comment: Have you added a servlet filter in web.xml?

Comment: how you do that ? sorry it is all config by annotation